# Convert HAML code to normal HTML and code

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I am trying to implement a CSS globe style which I found from this link: https://speckyboy.com/particle-animation-code-snippets/ (Particle Orb CSS by Nate Wiley) style.

Here you can see that they are using SCSS code. I have converted that SCSS code CSS code. Now they also used following code in HTML portion:

```
%div.wrap
  -300.times do
    %div.c
```

How can I convert that code into normal HTML?

Comment: Just click on "View Compiled" below the snippet and you will get the `HTML` code

Comment: You are not meant to create CSS manually, that's not how SASS works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the compiled version.

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
  <div class='c'></div>
</div>
```